# unique enum name token determined during class initialization

Tags: java, groovy, enums, initialization

I've defined the following enum in Groovy, though for the purpose of this question it could be Java code:

```
enum FestivalType {

    BIG_MUSIC,
    SMALL_MUSIC,
    FILM,
    FOOD_AND_DRINK; 

    private static Set<String> allSearchTokens = new HashSet<String>();

    FestivalType() {
        String searchToken = this.name().tokenize('_').first().toLowerCase();

        if (searchToken in allSearchTokens) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate search token");

        } else {
            this.searchToken = searchToken;
            allSearchTokens.add(searchToken);
        }
    }

    final String searchToken;
}
```

What I'm trying to do in the constructor is establish whether the first token in the name of each enum constant is unique, where `_` is used as the token separator.

However, this code doesn't work because `allSearchTokens` is not initialized until after all the constants are instantiated, so I get a `NullPointerException` here

```
allSearchTokens.add(searchToken)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around this as follows:

```
public enum FestivalType {

    BIG_MUSIC,
    SMALL_MUSIC,
    FILM,
    FOOD_AND_DRINK;

    private static class SetHolder {
        static Set<String> allSearchTokens = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    final String searchToken;

    FestivalType() {
        String searchToken = name().split("_")[0].toLowerCase();

        if (SetHolder.allSearchTokens.contains(searchToken))
            throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate search token");

        this.searchToken = searchToken;
        SetHolder.allSearchTokens.add(searchToken);
    }
}
```

This compiles because of the java specification that all static initializers must be completed *before* the class is used. By making the Set a static field of a sttic inner class, you guarantee that it will be initialized before the first enum is constructed.

Also, I took the liberty of changing/fixing a few things in your code:

- Use a `Set` rather than a `List`: Values are unique
- Use `split()`: There is not such method `tokenize()` for `String` in java
- Remove `else`: After a `return` or `throws`, `else` is always redundant because execution of the block is halted by these keywords (there is no "else" to handle)

As an aside, this technique is also great for [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) of [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
public class MyLazySingleton() {
    private static class InstanceHolder {
        static MyLazySingleton INSTANCE = new MyLazySingleton();
    }

    public static MyLazySingleton getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

The `INSTANCE` field is only constructed when the `getInstance()` method is first called!

Look mom! Lazy initialization without locks, without null checks, without synchronization of any kind *and* 100% bulletproof! (Object deserialization hacks notwithstanding)

It's magic :)

Comment: Nice! I will use that mechanism instead of mine in the future.

Comment: very clever, thanks very much. BTW, `tokenize()` is a method that Groovy adds to the String class

Comment: I think I remember reading about using this technique for singleton constuction in the 2nd edition of Effective Java - required reading

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar and the following has worked for me:

```
enum MyEnum{
   Enum1, Enum2;

   private static List<String> myList;

   private static void addToList(MyEnum enum){
       if(myList == null){
           myList = new ArrayList<String>();
       }

       myList.add(enum.name());
   }

   private MyEnum(){
       addToList(this);
   }


}
```